# How to Mass Delete Images from Media Library

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, sql

I need your help. I am trying to mass delete attachments from a custom post type ('book') using a sql query. I found this snippet on the wordpress form: [Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/delete-100000-images-from-media-library?replies=8#post-3270530)

I tested it on my local computer, and it removes all of the attachments from my media library. Now, I would like to have your help in setting the query so that it will only target attachments(featured image and thumbnail) from my custom post type 'book'.

Thanks

Comment: is `post_type` also equal to book?

Comment: @ECarterYoung, Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with native WordPress codex calls like this
( source http://badlywired.com/technical-stuff/2014/11/10/code-to-delete-all-images-from-wordpress-or-nearly-all/ )

```
<?php
/*  create this code in a file in the main wordpress directory e.g. delmedia.php
and access it via mydomain.com/delmedia.php
*/
// Include the wp-load'er
include('wp-load.php');
$args= array(
'post_type'      => 'book', // obvious
'posts_per_page' => -1            // get them all 
);

// get all attachments post ids
$posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($posts as $post_id) {
   // get an array of image data
   $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id->ID );
   if (strpos($image_attributes[0], 'mystring') !== FALSE){
   echo 'Image Found : '.$image_attributes[0];
   if (false === wp_delete_attachment( wp_delete_attachment( $post_id->ID, true     ) ) ) {
       echo ' and delete failed!<br>';
     } else {
       echo ' and delete succeeded!<br>';
     }
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining two methods here:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => null,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post_id
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN
(
SELECT id
FROM wp_posts
    WHERE (post_type = 'book')
)
;
    }
};
```

then:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_type = 'book')
```

This should give you post types that are attachments and books combined...

Comment: OMG! So Simple.. I tried so many different variants, that is probably the only one I did not try. I will give it a try right now. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @E Carter Young, Unfortunately that did not do not work. The first query threw an error, so I changed it to this: DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE `post_id` IN
(
SELECT id
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE (post_type = 'attachment') AND post_type = 'book'
); .


For the second Query is not running  no matter what I try.

Comment: The final query is still not running.

Comment: This query doesn't make sense, post cannot simultaneously have two different post types.

Comment: @Rarst That's why I asked him if book was a post type... user is book at `category` or a `post  type`?

Comment: Based on what I am seeing here, attachments are logged in my database under post_type. @ECarterYoung, I think that he is implying that you have to tell mysql to look under the two post types. And if Mysql sees a match then they should be deleted, if attachment is a book. Maybe someone can chip in further solutions.

Comment: Where  are `books` logged?

Comment: Book is a custom post_type. It is logged under posts table

Comment: I believe user51781 wishes to delete attachments that are being used by instances of the 'book' CPT.

Comment: @vancoder, you are correct. I want to remove the attachments(thumbnails, etc) from post_type('book')

Comment: @ECarterYoung, I am going to ask the silliest question of 2014, so far. Where do I place the first code? I have tried plunking it into my sql edit and functions file to no avail.